# My app Blazor App is not adding _content folder on startup

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor application fails to find its css file on loading because the _content folder is not being generated.

is there any reason why this path would not be generated?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please replace the 'href' in line 23 with "/css/reeditor.css" and do the same for line 24. The '_content' is used when you want to include external libraries that are not part of the main application; in other words, it belongs to a different component library.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Thank you, these previously were external sources and I was treating them as such even after moving them within my web project. Thank you!!!